# Haskell defining Functor instance for an alternative Either data type

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, functor, type-mismatch, either

Going through Typeclassopedia to gain some routing working with type classes. Want to make an alternative to `Either` an instance of `Functor`, but even examining the definition of `Either` as an instance of `Functor` keeps getting me in trouble. 
Have this, but will not compile.

```
data Alt a b = Success a | Failure b deriving (Show, Eq, Ord) 

instance Functor (Alt a) where 
  fmap _ (Failure a) = Failure a
  fmap f (Success x) = Success (f x)  

    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b. (a1 -> b) -> Alt a a1 -> Alt a b
        at Brenty_tcop.hs:25:3-6
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at Brenty_tcop.hs:24:10-24
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘Success’, namely ‘(f x)’
      In the expression: Success (f x)
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at Brenty_tcop.hs:26:19)
        f :: a1 -> b (bound at Brenty_tcop.hs:26:8)
        fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Alt a a1 -> Alt a b
          (bound at Brenty_tcop.hs:25:3)
   |
26 |   fmap f (Success x) = Success (f x)
```

Comment: You reversed `a` and `b`. Should be `data Alt a b = Success b | Failure a`, since you want to apply `f` to the value of type `b`, not type `a`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am opposed to the vote to close this as a simple typographical error. Although it is a two-character change to fix, knowing how to make that change requires a fairly deep understanding of a variety of very on-topic Haskell concepts, and would not be found by a non-Haskell-expert doing a glorified spellchecking pass.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: thanks for keeping it open. I do understand Benjamin's elaborate explanation but otherwise would not have found it.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I tend to vote to close questions with that reason when they are (essentially) impossible for someone with a similar problem to find. It's a sad fact that it's really, really hard to search for information on typical type errors and find something *relevant*. Things with similar words are utterly irrelevant; things that are right on point have completely unrelated words.

Comment: @dfeuer Madderote has a similar (identical, in fact!) problem, and found(ed) this question. It would be a shame to close the question and deprive them of an answer just because some hypothetical future visitor hypothetically didn't find this question.

Comment: @DanielWagner IOW we should separate the concerns, stop worrying about searchability, concentrate on answering and let *SO+Google* worry about improving *their* search algorithms! :)

Comment: @Community: appreciate the efforts, comments and the great answer by Benjamin. Even if one does not immediately find the answer, it can still help someone that stumbled across this thread, as SO helped me many times when stuck.

Comment: @WillNess, I just don't see a way to make these things searchable without strong AI.

Comment: @dfeuer depends on what "these things" means. :) tags here seem relevant, so a search on tags along would do fine in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As @chepner says in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364861/haskell-trying-either-alternative#comment97453537_55364861), your code will compile if you switch the order of the type parameters,

```hs
data Alt b a = Success a | Failure b
```

or alternatively switch the *meaning* of the `Functor` instance, so that it maps over `Failure` and leaves `Success` alone.

```hs
instance Functor (Alt a) where
    fmap f (Success x) = Success x
    fmap f (Failure x) = Failure (f x)
```

Basically, the `Functor` type class only knows how to map over a type's last type parameter. So we had to rejig things so that we apply the function `f` to an occurrence of that last type parameter.

---

**Why** you can only map over the rightmost parameter is a very deep and interesting question. To understand this you have to understand *kinds*, which are an advanced feature of Haskell's type system.

You can think of kinds as being the "next level" of types, in some sense. Types classify values; kinds classify types. So `"foo"` is a `String`, and `String` is a type. In Haskell "type" is pronounced `*`.

```
-- :t in ghci asks for the type of a value-level expression
ghci> :t "foo"
"foo" :: String

-- :k asks for the kind of a type-level expression
ghci> :k String
String :: *
```

All ordinary types - those which can have values - have a kind of `*`. So `String :: *`, `Int :: *`, `Bool :: *`, etc.

Things get interesting when you start thinking about parameterised types. `Maybe` is not a type by itself - you can't have values of type `Maybe`, but you can have `Maybe Int`, `Maybe String`, etc. So `Maybe` is a sort of function - it takes a type as an argument and it produces a type. (`Maybe` is a *type constructor*, to use the technical term.)

```
-- Maybe is a function...
ghci> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *

-- and you can apply it to an argument to get a type
ghci> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

`Alt` is a two-parameter type function. Type functions are curried in Haskell, just like regular value functions, so `Alt` has a type of `* -> * -> *` (which really means `* -> (* -> *)`).

```
ghci> :k Alt
Alt :: * -> * -> *
```

Now, `Functor` is a *higher-order* type function. It takes an argument `f`, which itself is a type function. `Functor` on its own is not a valid type class constraint, but `Functor f` is.

```
ghci> :k Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

This means `Maybe` on its own, with a kind of `* -> *`, is a valid argument for the `Functor` type function. But `Int :: *` isn’t, and nor is `Maybe Int :: *`, and nor is `Alt :: * -> * -> *`. The error messages tell you about the kind mismatch:

```
ghci> :k Functor Int
<interactive>:1:9: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘Int’
      In the type ‘Functor Int’

ghci> :k Functor Alt
<interactive>:1:9: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Alt’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Alt’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
    • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘Alt’
      In the type ‘Functor Alt’
```

The kind system is there to prevent you from forming invalid types, just like how the type system prevents you from writing invalid values. If there was no kind system, and we were allowed to write `instance Functor Alt`, it would produce the following (nonsensical) type for `fmap`:

```hs
-- `Alt a` is not a valid type, because its second argument is missing!
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Alt a -> Alt b
```

So we need to turn `Alt :: * -> * -> *` into something of kind `* -> *`, in order to have a valid argument for `Functor`. `Alt` is a curried type function, so if we give it a single type argument, we'll get a type function back!

```
ghci> :k Functor (Alt Int)
Functor (Alt Int) :: Constraint
```

That's why the `instance` declaration says `instance Functor (Alt x)` - it needs to give `Alt` an argument (and in this case the argument can be any type `x` as long as its kind is `*`). Now we have `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Alt x a -> Alt x b`, which is a valid type expression.

So in general, the recipe for making a `Functor` instance is to start by giving arguments to your type until it only has one parameter left. That's why `Functor` only knows how to map over the rightmost type parameter. As an exercise you can try defining a `Functor` class which maps over the *second*-to-last type parameter.

This is a big topic so hopefully I haven't gone too fast. It's OK not to understand kinds straight away - it took me several tries! Let me know in the comments if there's anything you'd like me to explain further.

Comment: Hogson: great explanation. Thank you. I do understand the theory behind it, but never giving it any though that Functor is right-bound, so never even tried to reverse parameter order. Mapping it over `Failure` is also not a viable option I think. 
For any noob ready this: this is the reason I went over Brent Yorgey's Typeclassopedia again, to get this thorough understanding of types. Benjamin's explanation definitely added to that understanding, so to it into my own documentation.

Comment: @Madderote, mapping over failure is a different idea, but it turns out to make sense too. See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Data-EitherR.html#t:EitherR

Comment: @dfeuer: Hah! Thanks for pointing me to that. Back to Typeclassopedia to get some routine in all this.

Comment: Since `*` doesn't appear in standard Haskell syntax (you need `KindSignatures` or a similar extension to use it), and since GHC has been making the transition from `*` to `Type` for a few years, I think you should probably mention the new pronunciation (found in `Data.Kind`).