# Is it possible to make a Functor instance for a type parameter other than the last?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Sometimes there are data types that contain multiple type parameters (eg `Either a b` and `(a,b)`).  We can create a Functor instance for the `b` parameter which turns out to be pretty straight forward. But what about the `a` parameter? I know that one could wrap everything in a `newtype` with the parameters in reverse order, but is there a way to create the instance of a second order type class (is that the correct way to describe `Functor`/ `Applicative` / `Monad`?) directly on a parameter other than the last? I don't think so but I could not actually find that written down anywhere.

**Context:**

[Another question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55364861/2751851) was from a student studying Haskell who was trying to create a Functor instance for their own Either-like Type presumably as a class assignment. Unfortunately, they had defined their data type as `data Alt a b = Success a | Failure b` and could not get the functor instance to work because they wanted to fmap over the `a` parameter.  I was about to write that `Functor` instances only work for the last parameter when I realized that I did not actually know that for sure. Thus my question.

Comment: well there are always [Bifunctors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) - you could define a new typeclass which just included `first` from `Bifunctor` (presumably under some other name). I think the only reason the last parameter is "privileged" in the way you describe is that type application (like function application) is left-associative - so `Either a b` is the same as `(Either a) b`, and can't be rewritten as something applied to `a` (without some `newtype` shenanigans as you observe).

Comment: Also related: [*Are there “type-level combinators”? Will they exist in some future?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8248217/2751851)

Comment: I don't think this is actually an exact duplicate of either of the linked questions.

Comment: @John F. Miller: I asked the original questions. Benjamin Hodgson, Chepner and Daniel Wagner provided lots of useful information. I learned a lot from their comments in combination with getting my head around the Typeclassopedia. I am still a long way from the level of understanding these guys have of Haskell, but it nonetheless it fuels my enthousiasm to dive in deeper and deeper ;-)